# How to validate a fields which was created on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My concept is to create maximum 20 fields on button click "+", If you tap on "+" button then new field could be added, that was successfully done.. But now my problem is to do validation for the fields which was created on "+" button tap.

I have code for validation, but it is working for only one field.. Can any one please help me to work on all the fields.
 Here is my sample code..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery - v1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myform').validate({ 
    rules: {
        userid: {
            required: true,

        },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});

});
</script>
<script>
var field = 1;
function add_fields() 
{
field++;
var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
var divtest = document.createElement("div");
divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Field '+ field +':</div><input            type="text" name="userid " id="userid' + field +'" maxlength="50"    placeholder="User ID"  class="userid"/></div>';
objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="+" />
<div id="room_fileds">    
<div class="label">Field 1:</div>  
<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" maxlength="50" placeholder="User ID"  class="userid"/><br>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To start with, you need to rename the inputs to `name="userid[]"` if you want mutliple fields with the same name. This will give you an array of inputs, otherwise you will only get one of them when you post your form.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that validation is not applying on dynamically added inputs.

For that, you need to add rules for newly created inputs by

```
$('input').rules('add', 'required')
```

Comment: @Nithya : Is everything ok ? you got the success ?

Comment: @Nithya Did you understand the problem ? you need to apply the rules to the newly added inputs before validating them..

Comment: @Nithya No problem glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

In your add fields method, you will have to re-validate the form and add a new rule.

```
<script>
var field = 1;
function add_fields() 
{
    field++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Field '+ field +':</div>    <input type="text" name="userid " id="userid' + field +'" maxlength="50"    placeholder="User ID"  class="userid"/></div>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    $('#myform').validate();
    $("input#userid" + field).rules("add", "required");
}
</script>
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Comment: Thanks.. But your code is working for first 2 fields from my end not more than 2 fields that..

Comment: You should check if the `id` of the fields matches with `"input#userid" + field`

Comment: Since you are adding fields dynamically and you have the `id` set for each input, please make sure all ids are unique if they aren't then it's going to cause the jquery to break

Comment: great, happy to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Count you appended div on add more button click :

```
function add_fields()  {
  var apendedDivCount = 1;
  apendedDivCount = document.querySelectorAll('.userid').length; // Count of appended div with class "userid"
  if (apendedDivCount < 21) { // Condition to allow maximum 20 userid class div
    field++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Field '+ field +':</div>
    <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid' + field +'" maxlength="50" placeholder="User ID" class="userid"/></div>';
objTo.appendChild(divtest);
  } else {
      alert ("You can't add more than 20");
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually my question is for validation... Anyway thank you i have accepted your answer as well..